# set array element object property based on the presence of an element of another array with the same id using array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

The title is very wordy, so I will demonstrate the idea with an example and a working code:

Consider a large song library available in a store. Lets call it "bigarray". A client has his/her own personal library of purchased songs from that store: "smallArray". BigArray elements has a property "purchased". I need to set that property to "true" if there is a match by id between songs of both arrays. A working code example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < smallArray.length; j++) {
    if (bigArray[i].id === smallArray[j].id) {
      bigArray[i].purchased = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to program that using array methods like map, filter etc. with predicate functions possibly in one line, instead of a double for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first create a set of ids from the objects in your `smallArray`, then use `.map()` on your `bigArray` to update the `purchased` property to `true` or `false` based on whether the set has the id of the current object from the big array:

```
const smallSet = new Set(smallArray.map(({id}) => id));
const result = bigArray.map(obj => ({...obj, purchased: smallSet.has(obj.id)}));
```

You could also use `.some()` to determine if your `smallArray` has an object that matches an id from your `bigArray`, this has a worse time-complexity of O(n*k) compared to using the set which is O(n+k), but is more suitable for a "one-liner" if that's what you're after:

```
const result = bigArray.map(obj => ({
  ...obj, 
  purchased: smallArray.some(item => item.id === obj.id)
}));
```

---

Both of these create new object references for each object in the new array, even if you're not updating the `purchased` property. To create new objects just for the object you're updating, you can use the result of `.has()` or `.some()` as the conditional operand like so:

```js
bigArray.map(obj => smallSet.has(obj.id) ? {...obj, purchased: true} : obj);
```